# Why a figure's Axes is not created?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

I'm trying not to use pyplot, but with the code below I only print a completely white figure.

I found with 'fig.axes' that no axes at all is created for 'fig', although 'ax' is a 'matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes' instance. I'm wondering why...

(I know that there are other ways to do obtain the plot, but my question is "what is wrong/missing here?").

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.axes import Axes

from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
from numpy import random 

data = [random.randn(5) for i in range(5)]

fig = Figure(figsize = (20,10))
canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(fig)

ax = Axes(fig, [0.1,0.1,0.5,0.7])

ax.pcolormesh(data)

canvas.print_figure('test')
```

Comment: What are you expecting for output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the axes is not added to the figure. Usually you would add an axes via any of the figure's methods, like `fig.add_axes()` or `fig.add_subplot()`

Doing that here, e.g.

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)  # instead of ax = Axes(fig, [0.1,0.1,0.5,0.7])
```

gives you the desired output.

There is really no reason not to use those methods. If you instantiate the `Axes` yourself, you need to call it

```
ax = Axes(fig, [0.1,0.1,0.5,0.7])
fig.add_axes(ax)
```

but this is really just one extra line and no benefit compared to

```
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.5,0.7])
```

Comment: Thank you @ImportanceOfBeingErnest! So what does `fig` in `ax = Axes(fig, [...])` is used for if it doesn't specificate the figure to which add the axes?

Comment: An axes needs to be created in an figure. That's what `Axes(fig, ..)` makes sure. However it does not get automatically added to the figure. This is all internat stuff, you normally wouldn't need to care about. Just using the figure methods to add an axes should be enough.